# Tag-dispatching based specialization for platform identification and emulation in C++ code

Tags: c++, c++11, cross-platform

## Background

Recently I want to refactor some platform-dependent low level APIs in my framework, written in C++11. Current APIs support different platforms by conditional inclusion which select one of the all possible implementation at compile-time. However, there are some cases the APIs should support more options, i.e., to *emulate* other platforms. Then I can redirect current APIs to these newly added emulation APIs.

Since the platform set is still determined totally at compile-time, I can use techniques like template specialization to keep runtime overhead away. However, the potential code base is large. Using class template specializations for each APIs (esp. free functions) would bloat code *a lot*. Function templates (if directly used without wrappers) would easily messed up overloading, also hard to figure out how to specify the order for matching. Thus I think using of tag dispatching may be better.

To illustrate the idea, here is one example:

Currently:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define Platform_Win32 1
#endif

inline char
GetNativePathSeparator()
{
#if Platform_Win32
    rerturn '\\';
#else
    return '/';
#endif
}
```

In future:

```
#define Platform_Win32_ID 0x0001 // some hard-coded magic number here...

#ifdef _WIN32
#define NativePlatform Platform_Win32_ID
#endif

template<std::uintmax_t ID>
using PlatformID = std::integral_constant<std::uintmax_t, ID>;

// For "all" platforms, as the default fallback.
struct BaseTag
{};

struct Win32Tag : BaseTag, PlatformID<Platform_Win32_ID>
{};

struct NativePlatformTag : BaseTag, PlatformID<NativePlatform>
{};

// The new emluation APIs. These APIs should be available for all host platforms, even the actual implementation used depends on the emulated target platform.

inline char
GetPlatformPathSeparator(Win32Tag)
{
    rerturn '\\';
}

inline char
GetPlatformPathSeparator(BaseTag)
{
    rerturn '/';
}

// Hmm... the implementation is even "portable"!
inline char
GetNativePathSeparator()
{
    return GetPlatformPathSeparator(NativePlatformTag());
}

// Note there would be many APIs like this.
// Macros can be used here to simplify the code for forwarding calls and make it easy enough to maintain, but it is relative complex for template specialization approach.
```

But things are not always so simple. Platform neutrality itself is already a monster...

I may need:

```
struct POSIXTag : BaseTag // POSIX is based on ISO C, which is nearly the "base" of all C++ implementations, no need to dig deeper...
{};

struct UNIXTag : POSIXTag // SUS is based on POSIX.
{};

struct OSXTag : UNIXTag // Now OS X is a UNIX.
{};
```

Still OK... But what if something not quite confident...?

```
struct GNUTag : POSIXTag // (perhaps not quite true)
{};

struct LinuxTag : GNUTag // (mainstream userland only?)
{};

struct AndroidTag : LinuxTag // (mostly true using C/C++?)
{};

struct BSDTag : POSIXTag // (somewhat questionable...)
{};

struct OSXTag : BSDTag // (ditto)
{};

// #ifdef __CYGWIN__ ??
// #if defined(_NEWLIB_VERSION) && defined(__SCLE) ??
```

Or even (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/help/codes.html):

```
namespace POSIXTags
{

struct XSI : POSIXTag
{};

struct XSR : XSI
{};

struct SHM : POSIXTag
{};

struct AIO : POSIXTag
{};

struct BAR : POSIXTag
{};

struct CPT : POSIXTag
{};

struct CS : POSIXTag
{};

//...

}
```

Or worse:

```
//...
struct POSIX2013Tag : POSIXTag // XXX: POSIX2008Tag? What about depercation and removal of APIs?
{};

#if _POSIX_SOURCE >= 200809
using POSIXTag = POSIX2013Tag;
#else
//...
#endif
```

Sigh... That's enough ... (Conditional inclusion everywhere is already NG.)

## My questions

Is there any prior art?

More specifically, I am interested in following aspects of the details:

Should there be `virtual` in the *base-specifier* of base tag classes?

- If so, could the mainstream implementations (recent/trunk versions of G++/Clang++/MSVC++, etc) optimize the runtime overhead away like the simple `std::iterator_tag` cases?
- If not, are there any other solutions to address the background problem here generally and (more) gracefully?

Note the virtual base approach has two major benefits:

- To explicitly keep the base not duplicated occasionally. This is notably different as simple cases like `std::iterator_tag` whose hierarchy design is stable/almost fixed at very early time and not likely to be extended later (frequently). (Although there exists [proposed new iterator category design](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html).)
- Allow users to be agnostic to order of template arguments and precise knowledge about feature sets/platforms overlapping represented among *all* the different identifiers introduced here. It is natural that most users should even not be required to know the *existence* of all supported platforms if they have not use these platform-specific interface. It also eases the maintenance work of these platform-specific APIs. This can be achieved by providing helper tag types like `UnionOfPlatforms<A, B, C>` being effectively equivalent with `UnionOfPlatforms<B, A, C>`, to mimic the equivalence between `#if Platform_A || Platform_B || Platform_C` and `#if Platform_B || Platform_A || Platform_C`. In aspect of implementation, this is a significant problem because the C++ overloading resolution (esp. exact match) rules are based on nominal typing. If I occasionally messed up the order, it is likely hard to test and debug. (What if `Platform_B` and `Platform_C` have some common features, or even one is a subset of the other? To make the overloading works, ambiguity on bases is not allowed.) Note the main part of this problem is essentially the simplified instance of (compile-time) meta [sum types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), which C++ type system cannot easily handle well in general.

Here is a more specific "real world" example for the second point:

```
struct Platform_Win32 /*: virtual Platform_WinNT */
{};

struct Platform_Win64 : /*virtual*/ Platform_Win32
{};

struct Platform_MinGW32 : /*virtual*/ Platform_Win32
{};

struct Platform_MinGW64 : /*virtual*/ Platform_MinGW32
{};
```

(This case has already being simplified. Here I don't use `std::integral_constant` stuff to link the macro values and tags together, and have assumed all Win32-compatible platforms are based on WinNT, no Win16/Win9x/WinCE, and I have not yet consider I should support WinRT, or even Wine...)

Comment: Just a rough overview of what I do: Multiple class hierarchies for features. Eg, UnixApi and UnixUserland with Unix as a child for convenience. As many hierarchies and fine grained as required. Have a PlatformProvides<typename...> for the current platform as the tag to call with and a PlatformRequires<typename...> as the type for your functions. The PlatformRequires then has one sfinae constructor that is disabled unless all types in PlatformRequires are convertible from something in PlatformProvides. Really just a more complex version of tag dispatching and only requires one case of sfinae.

Comment: @John5342 Good point about splitting platform feature check interface as "provides" and "requires". It should be clearer and more flexible to reflect my original intent, so here is my +1. The problems of the necessity of "virtual" in tag hierarchies remains, though.

Comment: In your example you may want virtual inheritance because you are trying to pull multiple features into a single type in the inheritance tree. My solution allows you to have multiple separate inheritance trees and in the process neatly side stepping any potential need  for diamond inheritance.

Comment: @John5342 I realized what I need mostly here is concept/constraint-based overloading mechanism. I admit to introduce virtual bases on level of feature sets/platforms is probable evil, because it allows vague abstraction and hierarchies to live. But I still want to see some more detailed implementation possibilities, like https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/utility/concepts.hpp#L198.

Answer (score 1):

Members can be multiply inherited. A member name found in multiple bases is still usable as long as all the declarations found are the same. There does need to be an explicit scope operator to do the name lookup; this solution can’t work purely as implicit conversion.

```
struct foo_bar_tag {
    typedef foo_bar_tag foo_tag;
};

struct a_tag : foo_bar_tag {};
struct b_tag : foo_bar_tag {};
struct d_tag : a_tag, b_tag {};

template< typename has_foo_tag >
typename has_foo_tag::foo_tag
slice_foo_tag( has_foo_tag ) { return {}; }

void f( foo_bar_tag );
void f( foo_baz_tag );

template< typename full_tag >
void g( full_tag t ) {
    f( t ); // error, ambiguous base conversion
    f( slice_foo_tag( t ) ); // OK
    f( typename full_tag::foo_tag{} ); // OK
}
```

The member typedef can be gotten for free (as the injected-class-name) if the tag base type is templated.

```
template< typename >
struct foo_tag {};

struct a_tag : foo_tag< bar > {};
struct b_tag : foo_tag< bar > {};
struct d_tag : a_tag, b_tag {};

void f( foo_tag< bar > );
void f( foo_tag< baz > );

// Rest of example is the same.
// foo_tag< bar >::foo_tag is a typedef to foo_tag< bar >.
```

Comment: Interesting about the injected-class-name part. Still too bad for the ambiguity of calling `f(t)`.

Answer (score 0):

**For reference:**

You might want to take a look at GTK (or maybe you already have) how they have done the OS adaptation layer. It might be a nice reference. It
advertises to work on Unix/Linux, Windows and OS/X

http://www.gtk.org/download/

**About the design:**

What I would do here is to divide the problem into API part and implementation part. API would handle part of the OS differences and the implementation part would do the rest. And how to decide which does what?
That comes from good API practices.

For instance OS version dependencies would go to the implementation part.
Also some very similar OS:es can be combined. If you go to the extreme,
you can create two OS adapters: general and windows. :-)

**About the virtual members:**

Generally, template programming and virtual members are seen as alternatives to each other. You know, fast accurate code, automatic type-check versus ability to do polymorphism.

Here I don't see what would be the benefit of including both the patterns in the same solution. It confuses people. But that's - of course - just my opinion.

Comment: What you have suggested is I already had. In fact, the current solution is somewhat more sophisticated: I have explicitly supported for adding freestanding (in ISO C/C++ sense) implementations (with limitation, though), that is, possible to not require an OS at all. Not all platform-dependent implementation are the same. Some of them are valuable to be reused elsewhere. So I want to have more ability beyond the 2-layer design, to expose these "implementation" as new set of lower level APIs. And "virtual" here is not for members, but for base classes. I need no virtual member functions.

Comment: I see. Maybe I was not much of use then.